# Type something in the input element and the page is stuck

Tags: next.js

I am practicing with Nextjs 13.4 and I have a problem when working with Form. I have a page todo list and in this page I have a TodoList component and a AddTodo component. AddTodo component is a client component where I can submit a new todo to the server with a form. When I try to type something in the input box, the page get stuck, meaning that I can not implement any user interactivity. My page get stuck with no errors when I run npm run dev or npm run build. Please help me. Below is my code:

Here is the AddTodo component:

```
"use client";

import handleAddTodo from "@/lib/handleAddTodo";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default async function AddTodo() {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("");

  const handleChangeName = function (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleAdd = async function (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name) {
      await handleAddTodo(name);
      router.refresh();
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
      <input onChange={handleChangeName} type="text" />
      <button>Add Todo</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here is the function to post a new todo and I have tested it with Postman:

```
export default async function handleAddTodo(name: string): Promise<void> {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/todos", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name }),
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("add todos error");
  }

  return;
}
```

Here is the whole page:

```
import { Metadata } from "next";
import AddTodo from "./components/AddTodo";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";

//SET REVALIDATE 0 TO MAKE THE PAGE RENDERED AS A SSR PAGE (NO DATA CACHING)
export const revalidate = 0;

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Todo list",
};

export default function Todos() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
      <AddTodo />
      {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
      <TodoList />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `input` element you did not set the value prop. I think your state gets updated but not input.

```
<input onChange={handleChangeName} value={name} type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you but that is not the point. The value is set to show the value of input element in the console. It does not update the state. I only need to run the function in onChange attribute to update my state. i do not want to log the value to the console.

Comment: Your button also should have ‘type:submit’

Comment: type: submit is the default value. I think I do not need that.

Comment: `AddTodo()` is client component. can  you remove the `async`  from `async function AddTodo()`

Comment: So do you mean that client component can not be created from an async function? If yes, can you please give me a link leading to the document. I have read the whole document but I do not know about this. I deleted it and it works.

Comment: async works only for server components.